docker image for amd64 is 6 times bigger than arm64
I'm building a Docker image for my Python Flask application on my Mac, based on the python:3.11-slim image. I've noticed a significant size discrepancy between the linux/amd64 and linux/arm64 targeted images:

linux/amd64 image size: ~6GB
linux/arm64 image size: ~1GB

This 6x size difference persists even when building from Docker Cloud or GitHub, ruling out any local environment issues.
Dockerfile:
# Stage 1: Builder
FROM python:3.11-slim AS compile-image

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

# Copy requirements first for better cache utilization
COPY ./chatbot/chatbot_requirements.txt .

# Create virtual environment and install dependencies
RUN python -m venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r chatbot_requirements.txt && \
    rm -rf /root/.cache/pip chatbot_requirements.txt

# Stage 2: Final
FROM python:3.11-slim AS runtime-image

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV PYTHONPATH="/app/:/app/chatbot/"
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

# Create a non-root user
RUN useradd -m appuser

WORKDIR /app

# Copy the virtual environment from the builder stage
COPY --from=compile-image /opt/venv /opt/venv

# Copy application files
COPY --chown=appuser:appuser ./chatbot/ /app/chatbot/
COPY --chown=appuser:appuser .env .

# Switch to non-root user
USER appuser

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["python", "chatbot/api/chatbot_endpoint.py"]

Requirements:
python-dotenv
pydantic
pydantic-settings
pinecone
langchain
langchain-pinecone
langchain-openai
langchain-huggingface
langserve
langgraph
fastapi
uvicorn
sse_starlette

Why is there such a significant size difference between the linux/amd64 and linux/arm64 images? How can I reduce the size of the linux/amd64 image to be closer to that of the linux/arm64 image?
I've tried building on different platforms (local Mac, Docker Cloud, GitHub) with the same results.

Can you list the contents of both images to see which specific files are larger than their counterparts?

biggest difference is :
Downloading torch-2.4.1-cp311-cp311-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (797.1 MB)
against 80mb for arm64 i don't even use torch. no inference inside my server only calling endpoints

and Downloading nvidia_cublas_cu12-12.1.3.1-py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (410.6 MB)
Downloading nvidia_cudnn_cu12-9.1.0.70-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (664.8 MB)
That are inexisting in  in arm
do you have an idea how to avoid them ?

Answer: Docker Image Size Discrepancy Solution
I found the root cause of the size discrepancy between the linux/amd64 and linux/arm64 images. The issue was related to unnecessary dependencies being installed for the amd64 architecture, specifically large machine learning libraries that weren't actually needed for the application's functionality.
Root Cause
The langchain-huggingface package was pulling in:
torch (797.1 MB for amd64 vs 80 MB for arm64)
NVIDIA CUDA libraries (only for amd64):
nvidia_cublas_cu12 (410.6 MB)
nvidia_cudnn_cu12 (664.8 MB)
These libraries were not being installed on the arm64 architecture, leading to the significant size difference.
However just for my personal knowledge do you have any tips how i can only use a subset of langchain_HUGGINFACE without installing torch ?
